# Why fgrep is acting weird?

Tags: macos, awk, grep

I am trying to use grep to extract the matching words from file1 in file2 and directing to output file.

I have file1

```
Acetoanaerobium sticklandii
Acetobacter pasteurianus
```

like >1000 species.

File2

```
>WP_013360383.1 ATP-dependent Clp protease ATP-binding subunit [Acetoanaerobium sticklandii]
>WP_013360396.1 ATP-dependent Clp protease ATP-binding subunit [Acetoanaerobium sticklandii]
>WP_003623694.1 multidrug efflux RND transporter permease subunit [Acetobacter pasteurianus]
>WP_003624003.1 superoxide dismutase [Acetobacter pasteurianus]
>WP_003624029.1 UDP-galactopyranose mutase [Acetobacter pasteurianus]
>WP_003624540.1 mannose-1-phosphate guanylyltransferase/mannose-6-phosphate isomerase [Acetobacter pasteurianus]
>WP_077905956.1 effector protein [Salmonella enterica]
>WP_077905962.1 type III secretion system YopJ family effector AvrA [Salmonella enterica]
>WP_005544680.1 3-deoxy-8-phosphooctulonate synthase [Aggregatibacter actinomycetemcomitans]
>WP_005545812.1 MFS transporter [Aggregatibacter actinomycetemcomitans]
>WP_005546163.1 UTP--glucose-1-phosphate uridylyltransferase GalU [Aggregatibacter actinomycetemcomitans]
```

and so on..

when I am using the code

```
grep -f file1 file2 > output
```

or

```
fgrep -f file1 file2 > output
```

The resulting output is the list containing the last line of file1 and remaining input list is ignoring by grep. Even with -w option also the output is same.

Why the grep is behaving like this?
Is it problem with my shell? 
I am using MacBook with Mojave OS version.

Please suggest me equivalent awk commands.

I tried

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$NF in a{print}' file1 file2 > output
```

but resulted empty file.

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in code form, could you please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS and let us know then, as its not looking clear as of now.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Generic and faster solution than my 2nd solution here. This will look for string from `[` to `]` in Input_file2 irrespective of field's hard-coding here.

```
awk '
{ gsub(/\r/,"") }
FNR==NR{
  array[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/\[[^]]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
(val in array)
' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Added detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
{ gsub(/\r/,"") }
FNR==NR{                                  ##Checkiing condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE hen file1 is being read.
  array[$0]                               ##Creating array with index of current line.
  next                                    ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
match($0,/\[[^]]*/){                      ##Using match to match from [ to till ] in line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)       ##Creating val which has sub-string from RSTART  to RLENGH here.
}
(val in array)                            ##Checking condition if val is present in array then print that line.
' file1 file2                             ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. This is more generic solution since field number is NOT hard coded in solution but this code will work irrespective of field numbers here.

```
awk '{ gsub(/\r/,"") } FNR==NR{array[$0];next} {for(i in array){if(match($0,i)){print;next}}}' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                    ##Starting awk program from here.
{ gsub(/\r/,"") }
FNR==NR{                 ##Checking condition FNR==NR if that's true then do following.
  array[$0]              ##Creating an array with index of current line.
  next                   ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i in array){       ##Looping through array here.
    if(match($0,i)){     ##Checking if current key is present  in current line then do following.
      print              ##Printing current line here.
      next               ##next will skip further statements from here.
    }
  }
}
'  file1 file2           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder..Thanks and First solution gives the exact output like grep i.e. extract the matches from the last line of file and ignoring the remaining.

Comment: @ThulasiR, Hi Thulasi, solutions worked for me for given samples,could you please do let me know what exactly didn't work here?

Comment: I don't know why it is happening? There is no problem with code and this is very easy task. Either problem with my input file or maybe shell.

Comment: @ThulasiR,could you please check your files if they have carriage returns. Do a command like `cat -v file1` and `cat -v file2`  if they have carriage returns then lemme know?

Comment: Thanks..I found carriage returns in file1 but not in file2

Comment: @ThulasiR, Cool, knew it. Could you please check my edited 1st solution I have taken care of control M characters in it, should work now, lemme know?

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't able to know that it is problem with input file if you didn't ask me to check for carriage returns. Otherwise I would have gone mad by thinking why such small coding solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your match condition `$NF in a`, means to match `sticklandii]` to your full line content in first file.

A better approach would be to set delimiter to process the whole string inside `[..]` in second file against first file

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ a[$0]; next } $2 in a' f1 FS='[][]' f2
```

The `FS='[][]'` before second file is to set the field separator to `[]` which means you can access the entries within `[..]` by column numbers which is `$2` in your given case.

---

As for your original problem `fgrep` not working, you need to add the `-F` flag to make the strings from second file as "fixed" strings and not regex strings. So you can do

```
fgrep -Ff file1 file2
```

Comment: Normally `fgrep` is the same as `grep -F`

Comment: Hi Inian, AWK didn't give the out put and grep, again same. It matched the last species of file and gave the result.

Comment: @ThulasiR: The `awk` command produces the output as expected with your given samples. I tested it. Can you post the output of `file file1` and `file file2` to see if they don't contain Windows line endings

Comment: Frankly speaking. Maybe it worked with the demo files but when I am working with 1000 species list. It is not giving any output. Is it may be my problem with my file1??

Comment: Yes @ThulasiR, your file encoding could be a problem. Can you post the output I asked for? `file file1` and `file file2` and post the `awk` version GNU or other?

Comment: Thanks here it is; file1: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators; file 2: ASCII text. As I expected it is problem with input files

Comment: @ThulasiR: Theres your problem. CRLF line endings are different from standard Unix style endings. Google CRLF vs Unix endings

Comment: @ThulasiR: Run `unix2dos <file>` on both the files and re-run the awk command, it should work then

Comment: Thank you. Here after I will take care of my text files, especially when it comes from windows system.